# customizing git commands in bash_profile to auto index to next branch

Tags: linux, bash, git, terminal, git-bash

Below is my custom gitp command which works great (with psuedo-code). I would like to add to the script by having it automatically auto-index and checkout to a new branch.
Hoping there is a command-line bash whiz who can figure it out! :)

```
    previous_branch_num = 0;
    gitp() {
      git add -A &&
      git commit -m "${1?'Missing commit message'}" &&
      git push      
      git checkout -b "v{++previous_branch_num}" //<--psuedo code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

previous_branch_num=0

gitp() {
  git add -A &&
  git commit -m "${1?'Missing commit message'}" &&
  git push      
  git checkout -b "v$((++previous_branch_num))" # <-- real code
}
```